# Anyone know how to do angular `ng-mouseover` events on SVG?

Tags: angularjs, svg

Many of the angular events work with SVG elements like `ng-click` or `ng-mousedown`but I'm having trouble with `ng-mouseover`. Anyone know if you can make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm not sure if you can get `ng-mouseover` to work but I accomplished the same thing using `ng-mousemove`